# Add custom properties to adminhtml Form Field

Tags: magento-1.6, adminform

I want to have some custom properties added to a form in admin section. My code is as follows.

```
    $fieldset->addField('customer_ids', 'multiselect', array(
        'name'      => 'customer_ids[]',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Customers'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Customers'),
        'required'  => true,
        'values'    => $allcustomers,
        'class'     =>'chosen-select',
        'style'     => 'width: 700px',
        'tabindex'  => '10',
        'data-placeholder' => 'Select customer...,'
        ));
```

This is not working for the following two attributes,

```
'tabindex'  => '10',
'data-placeholder' => 'Select customer...,'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Multiselect`.
Here is the list of allowed html attributes:

```
public function getHtmlAttributes()
{
    return array('title', 'class', 'style', 'onclick', 'onchange', 'disabled', 'size', 'tabindex');
}
```

You need to create the class which will extend `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Multiselect` and there you should rewrite method `getHtmlAttributes` adding new attributes that you need.

Then before adding the field to the form write this:

```
$fieldset->addType('extended_multiselect','MyCompany_MyModule_Lib_Varien_Data_Form_Element_ExtendedMultiSelect');
```

And after

```
$fieldset->addField('customer_ids', 'extended_multiselect', array( ...
```

Comment: good and clean answer. More power to you :-)

Comment: Just one word to describe your answer, "Awesome"

Comment: @DushyantJoshi, you are welcome :)